# cmake install pointing to minimum python version when installing opencv

Tags: python, opencv, cmake, python-3.6, nvidia-jetson-nano

Used this to build inside `release` directory of `opencv`

To build `OpenCV` inside the virtual environment `offersTest`

`cmake -D WITH_CUDA=ON -D CUDA_ARCH_BIN="5.3" -D CUDA_ARCH_PTX="" -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib-4.0.0/modules -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON -D WITH_LIBV4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/.virtualenvs/offersTest/bin/python3 -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..`

I wanted the `OpenCV` to be installed inside the virtual environment `offersTest` as i have specified the path here

`-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/.virtualenvs/offersTest/bin/python3`

during `make -j2` the interpreter points to the correct location of the python

[image]

But during `sudo make install`

It prefers the minimum python version `2.7`

[image]

Comment: Please, use **text** representation for logs instead of *images* whenever possible. See also [ask].

Comment: Normally, after `make` completes, `make all` doesn't re-run configuration and building steps: These steps are re-run only when CMake (or make) detects some changes.

Comment: How do i set the correct path?